# Script To Start Shopify Dev

Tags: node.js, shopify, posix

We develop Shopify themes with a JS bundler, for this we put all the Shopify content in a seperate folder, say "liquid", and then use this in our `package.json`:

```json
"start": "cd liquid && shopify switch --store=my-store.myshopify.com && shopify theme serve"
```

But then Shopify switched to Online Store 2.0 so we tried to adapt the script:

```json
"start": "cd liquid && shopify theme dev --store=my-store.myshopify.com",
```

Now it complains that it's not running in a theme directory, it seems to run in the root directory, not in `liquid`.  If I manually run `cd liquid` and then `shopify theme dev --store=my-store.myshopify.com` everything works fine.  What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why this might be happening. But = is not required after the --store flag. Can you try after removing that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).